# Terminology for "line with orientation"

Tags: direction

I'd like to know if there is a single word I could use to define a "line with an orientation".

This question is related to the one in "Terminology for diagonal line that also indicates orientation" but not quite the same as I might have an horizontal line pointing to the right or to the left.

I really want to convey the idea of an infinite line in both directions (hence different than ray or segment) but with a given direction, meaning that if you take a point and add a positive length you will always move in the direction defined along the line.

Comment: This question is related to the one in "Terminology for diagonal line that also indicates orientation" but not quite the same as I might have an horizontal line pointing to the right or to the left. I really want to convey the idea of an infinite line in both directions (hence different than ray or segment) but with a given direction, meaning that if you take a point and add a positive length you will always move in the direction defined along the line.

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/science/vector-physics ?

Comment: Nini - can you edit you question with the info in your comment? it's better if readers can get all the necessary info in one place (and may not look at comments).

Comment: Look at @k1eran’s comment. It is the answer. A vector in maths and physics has magnitude and it has direction. A mile to the North, a cm to the left, an infinite line to the East etc

Answer (score 1):

@k1eran has already said it, but I think the word you are looking for is *vector*.

Comment: Yep, "vector" is the proper math geek term.